# Why is this function out of scope (and another in the same included header isn't)?

Tags: c++, scope

Simplifying/psuedocoding what's going on in a rather large project ATM, I have the following function, in part:

```
helper_checkBypassControl(paramsX) {
Status status;

enableBypasses(paramsY);
status = setBypasses(paramsZ);
}
```

The header for the function calls in my helper function is included OK, and it must be, since both are in the same header, and enableBypasses works fine. Both of them return a status. setBypasses is a static function in that header (enableBypasses is simply of type Status), and when I compile via the CLI, I get an error that setBypasses is out of scope.

Is my understanding of static functions mistaken? How could a static function ever be out of scope, when the header is included and a call such as the above is made? Can someone perhaps give me an intuition of what could cause an out of scope error besides the obvious? I'm perplexed because both functions come from the same header, do similar things with similar params, but the latter is out of scope while the former isn't. If anything, I should think the static setBypasses should be recognized while there might be a problem with the regular enableBypasses, unless my understanding is flawed.

Hope this description is sufficient for someone to point me in the right direction! Tried to keep it general on purpose since there are many layers at work - let me know if more specifics are required to diagnose!

Comment: You should at least include your header. Please don't omit surrounding code, but of course you should omit nonrelevant functions of the header. In doubt post the whole header file.

Answer (score -2):

Try with static_class::method.